# Unit test code analysis using "sonar.*" property and maven-sonar-plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to do code analysis of Java unit test using maven sonar plugin. But the plugin doesn't seem to take into account my sonar properties "sonar.*". I've tried to modify simple examples and it did work either. According to [MSONAR-70](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSONAR-70), the issue has been fixed and I'm using the version 2.4.

For the test, I've tried it on a simple case:

- Clone [sonar-examples.git](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples.git)
- use the project *sonar-examples/projects/languages/java/maven/java-maven-simple* as example
- Renamed *src/main* to *src/test*
- In the pom.xml, add to the properties section :

  ```
  <sonar.sources>src/test/java</sonar.sources>
  <sonar.binaries>target/test-classes</sonar.binaries>
  ```
- Run mvn sonar:sonar.

--> the code analysis didn't took into account my settings. The project is created on SonarQube but code as not been analyzed.

If I use the sonar-runner command line, it's analyzing the code:

```
sonar-runner [...] -Dsonar.sources=src/test/java 
-Dsonar.binaries=target/test-classes
 -Dsonar.language=java
 -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
 -Dsonar.projectKey=org.codehaus.sonar:example-java-maven
 -Dsonar.projectName="Simple Java Maven Project"
 -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score -1):

According to a previous revision of the question, the OP solved their problem like this:

> We were using SonarQube 4.0 version. Updating the version to 4.4, made the properties be taken into account.

That was in 2014; the current version now is **5.5**.

The steps to upgrade can be found [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading):

> - Stop the old SonarQube server
> - Download and unzip the new SonarQube distribution in a fresh directory, let's say NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME.
> - Start it using the default H2 database and use the update center to install the plugins you need.
> - Manually install any custom plugins.
> - Stop the new server.
> - Update the content of the sonar.properties and wrapper.conf files located in the NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME/conf directory with the content of the related files in the OLD_SONARQUBE_HOME/conf directory (web server URL, database settings, etc.). Do not copy-paste the old files.
> - If a custom JDBC driver is used, copy it into NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/jdbc-driver/.
> - **Back up your database.**
> - **Remove the data/es directory.**
> - Start the new web server
> - Browse to `http://localhost:9000/setup` (replace "localhost:9000" with your own URL) and follow the setup instructions.